# Is it possible to report uid without setting custom dimension from Google Analytics?

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I used measurement protocol to track opened emails `<img src="https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&tid=UA-XXXXXXXX-X&cid={uid}&t=event&ec=email&ea=open&uid={uid}">`. Now I want to get every uid who opened email and all their sessions. Is it possible to achieve that? I did not create any custom dimensions before

Answer (score 1):

Nop, it's not possible, that is the main reason to duplicate the user id as a Custom Dimension. You can try to look for another way to disaggregate with other metric, but i think that will not be the same.
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets

Comment: How I can duplicate the user id for the next time?

Comment: Should I use web scraping?